# Python : Another 'NoneType' object has no attribute error

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup

For a newbie exercise , I am trying to find the meta tag in a html file and extract the generator so I did like this :

```
Version = soup.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})['content']
```

and since I had this error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I was thinking that working with exception would correct it, so I wrote :

```
try: Version = soup.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})['content']

except NameError,TypeError:

     print "Not found"
```

and what I got is the same error.

What should I do then ?

Comment: It sounds like `soup.find()` is returning `None`. According to the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find), that means it found nothing.

Comment: in some cases that metatag doesn't exist, and that's why I would like to test it, if it exists, I print it if not I print another message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `soup.find()` method did not find a matching tag, and returned `None`.

The `[...]` item access syntax looks for a `__getitem__` method, which is the source of the `AttributeError` here:

```
>>> None[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Test for `None` explicitly:

```
Version = soup.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})
if Version is not None:
    Version = Version['content']
else:
    print "Not found"
```

Your exception handling would work too, provided you use parenthesis to group the exceptions:

```
try:
    Version = soup.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})['content']
except (NameError, TypeError):
    print "Not found"
```

Without parenthesis you are telling Python to catch `NameError` exceptions and assign the resulting exception object to the local name `TypeError`. This `except Exception, name:` syntax has been deprecated because it can lead to exactly your situation, where you think you are catching two exceptions.

However, your code here should not throw a `NameError` exception; that'd be a separate problem better solved by instantiating your variables properly; the following would work just as well here:

```
try:
    Version = soup.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})['content']
except TypeError:
    # No such meta tag found.
    print "Not found"
```

Comment: To expand further, what you're doing with `except NameError, TypeError` is catching `NameError` and *assigning the caught exception* to the name `TypeError`. Since the code doesn't throw `NameError`, this `except` will never catch anything.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
content = None
Version = soup.find("meta", {"name":"generator"})
if Version:
    content = Version.get('content') 
    #or even
    #Version = Version.get('content')
else:
    print "Not found"
```

The issue is, [`soup.find`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) returns a `None` if match was not found, and extracting data out of `None` results in error.

Comment: Thanks it works. So there is no way to make the code shorter and avoid using two variables (Version and content) ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This is readable, and simple.. But if you do insist, you can just do `Version = Version.get('content')`